Understanding element access in nested struct arrays in C++
How does it work
    struct sct 
    {
        int t[2];
    };
    
    struct str 
    {
        sct t[2];
    };
    
    str t[2] = { {0, 2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7} };
    std::cout << t[1].t[0].t[1] << t[0].t[1].t[0]; 

it's weird for me that it can work like that and prints:
34

Can you provide some explanation ?

The elements just get filled in sequentially.  0, 2, 4, 6 get assigned to t[0].t[0].t[0], then t[0].t[0].t[1], then t[0].t[1].t[0], then t[0].t[1].t[1].  This behavior is a leftover from the very earliest days of C, before we had more strict typing.  What did you expect to happen?

"it's weird for me" hmm why whould that be? where fo you expect it to break and why?

No way to let you know where your expectations are violated if you don't advertise your expectations.
